# Who invented the standard construction of finite fields (and field extensions)?

Tags: math-history, finite-fields

The title says it all, but just to be clear I mean the construction of taking $k[x]$ modulo an irreducible polynomial of suitable degree.

Was it an open problem for any considerable amount of time, for example on how to construct all finite fields, that this technique solved?

Comment: This construction is not special to finite fields—you do the same thing for finite extensions of $\mathbb Q$, for instance.

Comment: Good point. edited.

Comment: I always thought that finite fields were called "Galois fields" because Galois investigated them.  Perhaps someone will tell us whether this is true.